# Multiprocessing python function for numerical calculations

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy, multiprocessing

Hoping to get some help here with parallelising my python code, I've been struggling with it for a while and come up with several errors in whichever way I try, currently running the code will take about 2-3 hours to complete, The code is given below;

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import Boltzmann, elementary_charge as kb, e
import multiprocessing
from functools import partial 
Tc = 9.2
x = []
g= []
def Delta(T):
'''
Delta(T) takes a temperature as an input and calculates a
temperature dependent variable based on Tc which is defined as a
global parameter  
'''
    d0 = (pi/1.78)*kb*Tc
    D0 = d0*(np.sqrt(1-(T**2/Tc**2)))
    return D0

def element_in_sum(T, n, phi):
    D = Delta(T)
    matsubara_frequency = (np.pi * kb * T) * (2*n + 1)
    factor_d = np.sqrt((D**2 * cos(phi/2)**2) + matsubara_frequency**2)
    element = ((2 * D * np.cos(phi/2))/ factor_d) * np.arctan((D * np.sin(phi/2))/factor_d)
    return element

def sum_elements(T, M, phi):
'''
  sum_elements(T,M,phi) is the most computationally heavy part
  of the calculations, the larger the M value the more accurate the 
  results are.
  T: temperature
  M: number of steps for matrix calculation the larger the more accurate the calculation
 phi: The phase of the system can be between 0- pi 
'''
    X = list(np.arange(0,M,1))
    Y = [element_in_sum(T, n, phi) for n in X]
    return sum(Y)

def KO_1(M, T, phi):
    Iko1Rn = (2 * np.pi * kb * T /e) * sum_elements(T, M, phi)
    return Iko1Rn

def main():
    for j in range(1, 92):
        T = 0.1*j
        for i in range(1, 314):
            phi = 0.01*i
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
            result = pool.apply_async(KO_1,args=(26000, T, phi,))
            g.append(result)
            pool.close()
            pool.join()    
     A = max(g);
     x.append(A)
     del g[:]
```

My approach was to try and send the KO1 function into a multiprocessing pool but I either get a `Pickling` error or a `too many files open`, Any help is greatly appreciated, and if multiprocessing is the wrong approach I would love any guide.

Comment: Instead of multithreading, I think you can reduce the runtime of your code a lot but using properly array operations instead of for loops, since your seems to involve rather simple math. (correct me if I'm wrong). This code looks like written by a C progammer ;) 

Check these: http://technicaldiscovery.blogspot.de/2011/06/speeding-up-python-numpy-cython-and.html

http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/PerformancePython.html

Comment: Iol I'm flattered :D @dnalow but sadly this was written by someone who was a chemist turned engineer who's new to programming, I was definitely interested in using the grid aspect of Numpy but I wasn't too sure about how I would implement it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested your code, but you can do several things to improve it.

First of all, don't create arrays unnecessarily. `sum_elements` creates three array-like objects when it can use just one generator. First, `np.arange` creates a numpy array, then the `list` function creates a list object and and then the list comprehension creates another list. The function does 4 times the work it should.

The correct way to implement it (in python3) would be:

```
def sum_elements(T, M, phi):
    return sum(element_in_sum(T, n, phi) for n in range(0, M, 1))
```

If you use python2, replace `range` with `xrange`.
This tip will probably help you in any python script you'll write.

Also, try to utilize multiprocessing better. It seems what you need to do is to create a `multiprocessing.Pool` object **once**, and use the `pool.map` function.

The main function should look like this:

```
def job(args):
   i, j = args
   T = 0.1*j
   phi = 0.01*i
   return K0_1(26000, T, phi)

def main():        
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4) # You can change this number
    x = [max(pool.imap(job, ((i, j) for i in range(1, 314)) for j in range(1, 92)]
```

Notice that I used a tuple in order to pass multiple arguments to job.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm loving the simplicity here and thank you so much for the tip will keep that in my pocket from now on, when Irun the code though I keep getting  `NameError: global name 'K0_1' is not defined`

Comment: The snippets are meant to replace `sum_elements` and `main` respectively.

Comment: yeah I did a straight substitution for `sum_elements` and `main` but when I run `main()` I get the error above

Comment: I'm so sorry it was my fault it should have been `KO_1` and not `K0_1`

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question, but if I may, I would propose how to speed up the code using simple numpy array operations. Have a look at the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.constants import Boltzmann, elementary_charge as kb, e
import time
Tc = 9.2
RAM = 4*1024**2 # 4GB

def Delta(T):
    '''
    Delta(T) takes a temperature as an input and calculates a
    temperature dependent variable based on Tc which is defined as a
    global parameter  
    '''
    d0 = (np.pi/1.78)*kb*Tc
    D0 = d0*(np.sqrt(1-(T**2/Tc**2)))
    return D0

def element_in_sum(T, n, phi):
    D = Delta(T)
    matsubara_frequency = (np.pi * kb * T) * (2*n + 1)
    factor_d = np.sqrt((D**2 * np.cos(phi/2)**2) + matsubara_frequency**2)
    element = ((2 * D * np.cos(phi/2))/ factor_d) * np.arctan((D * np.sin(phi/2))/factor_d)
    return element


def KO_1(M, T, phi):
    X = np.arange(M)[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]
    sizeX = int((float(RAM) / sum(T.shape))/sum(phi.shape)/8) #8byte
    i0 = 0
    Iko1Rn = 0. * T * phi
    while (i0+sizeX) <= M:
        print "X = %i"%i0
        indices = slice(i0, i0+sizeX)
        Iko1Rn += (2 * np.pi * kb * T /e) * element_in_sum(T, X[indices], phi).sum(0)
        i0 += sizeX
    return Iko1Rn

def main():
    T = np.arange(0.1,9.2,0.1)[:,np.newaxis]
    phi = np.linspace(0,np.pi, 361)
    M = 26000
    result = KO_1(M, T, phi)
    return result, result.max()

T0 = time.time()
r, rmax = main()
print time.time() - T0
```

It runs a bit more than 20sec on my PC. One has to be careful not to use too much memory, that is why there is still a loop with a bit complicated construction to use only pieces of X. If enough memory is present, then it is not necessary.

One should also note that this is just the first step of speeding up. Much improvement could be reached still using e.g. just in time compilation or cython.

Comment: I love this, it might not answer the question but this is defiantly helpful to a noob.

Comment: I forgot to mention that here i span a cube of datapoints, first dimension M, second dimension T, and third dimension phi. Internally I sum ofer the first dimension (.sum(0)) as it was done in the original